# Is gravity the result of protons and electrons?

Tags: gravity, magnetic-fields, atoms

I understand that gravity is the result of a curved space/time caused by mass. But is it possible that gravity is the result of protons and electrons magneticly interacting on a massive scale? Large masses are composed of a massive amount of atoms, which hold positive and negative magnetic charges that also interact with other massive objects around them. We see it at the atomic level how is it not possible that these interactions don't occur at a massive level?

Answer (score 7):

> is it possible that gravity is the result of protons and electrons magneticly interacting on a massive scale?

No, it is not even remotely possible. Gravity falls off as $r^{-2}$ and is isotropic. The magnetic force falls off as $r^{-4}$ or faster and exhibits a dipole or higher degree of anisotropy. Gravity is proportional to mass, magnetism is not. Magnetism is detectable by accelerometers, gravity is not. Gravity is always attractive, magnetism can be repulsive (especially in the solar system it would be impossible to get all of the bodies to mutually attract if they were magnetic). Magnetism exhibits dipole radiation gravity does not.

I am sure there are other differences, but in brief, no, there is simply no possibility whatsoever that gravity is a magnetic interaction.

Comment: *Magnetism is detectable by accelerometers, gravity is not.* You probably mean it the other way round.

Comment: No, I meant it as written. The magnetic force produces proper acceleration, the gravitational force does not.